# Check lack of diskspace and email me if it crosses threshold

Tags: windows, disk-space-utilization

I like to know the script which sends email when the server disk space crosses its threshold or critical limit set by me in Windows 2003. Please help.

thanks in advance,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 2):

I have limited experience with Windows, but we monitor all our Windows and Linux servers via SNMP.

On all Windows servers we installed the free [SNMP Informant](http://www.wtcs.org/informant/download.htm) software. SNMP Informant monitors the various server metrics, and makes them available via the SNMP protocol. On the Linux servers we installed Net-SNMP, which does the same.

Then, on a single server we installed [Zenoss Core](http://www.zenoss.com/product/core), a free monitoring system that polls each server, saves and graphs the data and sends alerts if it crosses thresholds.

It's a bit much if you're monitoring a single server, but highly recommended if you want to monitor several servers.

Comment: Ive heard of security concerns with Using SNMP as its not a very secure protocol by default?

Comment: Well, there's no encryption and very little authentication built into SNMP. I've simply used the firewall on each server to only allow access from the monitoring server to port 161 on the host.

Comment: +1 Use a real monitoring system (Zenoss is a good choice, but others will also do), rather than mess around with loads of custom scripts.

Comment: Re Security: SNMP is insecure in that it has no access control (at least the commonly deployed version). But as long as SNMP is configured read-only (the default usually) the risk is only in information disclosure. As long as you're behind a firewall, that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A real simple approach is to set up some alerts in perfmon - you could have the alert fire a script that e-mails you - it could fire something like sendmail to actually do the e-mail passing in arguments from the perfmon alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the first few links [here](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=windows+disk+space+script&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=8&oq=windows+disk+space+script&fp=8f75e31f6fdd9ab1)